# Logrotate not changing the active log file

Tags: java, spring, log4j, logstash, logrotate

I am using logrotate *without* *copytruncate* , so whenever my file gets rotated this happens:-

**Current status:**

*inode* = 23456 | *filename*=test.log | *size*=0.99G

**After rotation:**

*inode* = 23456 | *filename*=test.1.log | *size*=1G

*inode* = 23829 | *filename*=test.log | *size*=0K

**Problem**: Now all the new logs being generated after rotation are being pushed to test.1.log .So the size of test.log stays constant at 0K while test.1.log size keeps on increasing. While, the expected behaviour was that my application pushes the logs to the newly generated **test.log | inode=23829**

Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: What is your logrotate configuration? Have you tried **with** `copytruncate` or do you have a postrotate script?

Comment: @leandrojmp To avoid replicating of logs in logstash, I am not using copytruncate.

Comment: If I use copytruncate and not include the path of rotated file in logstash, I am missing on logs since logstash is not able to detect any kind of logrotation, so I am basically stuck at either replication of my logs or missing of my logs. Isn't there a perfect way to handle this situation?